# If I create customised cluster in Matter, how can I control that cluster by my own Android App?

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I have run thru the Matter documentation and going to create my own non-standard cluster for my own use case.
After that, I need to find the way to control those cluster thru Android.

So my question would be.
If I create customised cluster in Matter, how can I control that cluster by my own Android App?

I have tried to read thru the Android documentation, but cannot find any mentioning customised cluster access.

Comment: I think this PR will help you to add support for a custom cluster in chip libs. 
https://github.com/Lowpan-com/connectedhomeip/pull/4

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit long procedure to add custom cluster support in Android Chip libraries.

You need to do some modifications in ChipTool (connectedhomep repo), rebuild chiptool libs and use those libs in your project.

Prepare xml file that has your cluster definition, and do modifications as per the given steps in [this PR](https://github.com/Lowpan-com/connectedhomeip/pull/4).

Previously there is no documentation for custom cluster support but now Google has added a document for adding support of manufacturer cluster.
Here is a document : https://developers.home.google.com/matter/extensions/sample-mei-cluster#create_the_ms_source_code